# In an Android app how can I close the app after the activity phone call?

Tags: android

I built a simple Android app to call an underground garage number when I start the app. This works as expected. I would like to detect when the call activity ends so the app would close. Currently I have to end the app manually so I can use it again later.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:***********"));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
}
```

I've read about `onDestroy()` and `startActivityForResult` but I don't know how to use that against my `Intent` object. The only other thing I've done with Android is a `hello world` tutorial so I need a little handholding. Other search hits on SOF don't quite match or are so old the Android ecosystem might have moved on.

How can I close the app after the activity phone call?

Comment: "I would like to detect when the call activity ends so the app would close" -- if all you are doing is calling `startActivity()`, why not just follow it with a call to `finish()` to destroy this activity? Do you need your activity around during the call?

Comment: Why? Cause I didn't know about `finish()` :) Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

gradle

```
dependencies {
    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.2.2"
}
```

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private val dial = prepareCall(ActivityResultContracts.Dial()) { result ->
        finish()
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dial("123456789")
    }
}
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: Thank you for the answer, all I needed for my req. was `finish()` right after I `startActivity`